# PHP Merge child of an array into parent as independent

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
array(
    array(
    'drive'=>array('test1'),
    'wheel_drive'=>array('2WD','4WD')
    ),
    array(
        0=>array(
            'drive'=>array('test21','test31'),
            'wheel_drive'=>array('2WD','4WD')
        ),
        1=>array(
            'drive'=>array('test32'),
            'wheel_drive' => array('4WD')
        )
    ),
    array(
        'drive' => array('test4'),
        'wheel_drive'=> array('2WD','4WD')
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array(
    array('drive'=>array('test1'),'wheel_drive'=>array('2WD','4WD')),
    array('drive'=>array('test21','test31'),'wheel_drive'=>array('2WD','4WD')),
    array('drive'=> array('test32'),'wheel_drive' => array('4WD')),
    array('drive' => array('test4'),'wheel_drive'=> array('2WD','4WD'))
);
```

How can we get child array out of main array and then merge it into parent array as its node.

```
    function flattenArray($key, $array) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $k=> $element) {
        if (is_array($element)) {
            $result = array_merge($result, flattenArray($k, $element));
        } else {
            $result[$key][] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$outputArray = array();

foreach ($inputArray as $key=> $item) {
    $outputArray[] = flattenArray($key, $item);
}

print_r($outputArray);
```

I have this array in which I am trying to extract sub-array and merge into main array so that my result would be like this
one array with all child array with save depth.

Comment: You're mixing the `array(...)` and `[...]` notation, which is very confusing. Please choose one or the other. Also, I also don't see any real code that does something? Can you please clarify your question? See: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your input array is invalid as well as no code-effort shown. Please correct the input array as well as your attempted code

Comment: I added the last code, as I tried many attempts

Comment: I tried this code too :function flattenArray($key, $array) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $k=> $element) {
        if (is_array($element)) {
            $result = array_merge($result, flattenArray($k, $element));
        } else {
            $result[$key][] = $element;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$outputArray = array();

foreach ($inputArray as $key=> $item) {
    $outputArray[] = flattenArray($key, $item);
}
print_r($outputArray); But this not works

Comment: Please do not post longer pieces of code in a comment, as you can see it's not very readable.

Answer (score 1):

With a slight modification to your code you can extract the array you want:

```
$outputArray = array();

function flattenArray(&$output, $input)
{
    foreach ($input as $key=> $item) {
        if (in_array('drive', array_keys($item))) {
            $output[] = $item;
        } else {
            flattenArray($output, $item);
        }   
    }    
}

flattenArray($outputArray, $inputArray);

print_r($outputArray);
```

See: https://3v4l.org/Ut27X

That being said: The data array doesn't make sense. I think it would be better to work on the code that generates this data array. Prevent the problem from occurring in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = [
  [ 'drive' => [ 'test1' ], 'wheel_drive' => [ '2WD', '4WD' ] ],
  [
    [ 'drive' => [ 'test21', 'test31' ], 'wheel_drive' => [ '2WD', '4WD' ] ],
    [ 'drive' => [ 'test32' ], 'wheel_drive' => [ '4WD' ] ]
  ],
  [ 'drive' => [ 'test4' ], 'wheel_drive' => [ '2WD', '4WD' ] ]
];

$result = array_reduce(
  $input,
  static fn($carry, $item) => array_merge($carry, array_is_list($item) ? $item : [ $item ]),
  []
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function array_flatten($array, $depth = INF): array
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if (! array_is_list($item)) {
            $result[] = $item;
        } else {
            $values = $depth === 1
                ? array_values($item)
                : array_flatten($item, $depth - 1);

            foreach ($values as $value) {
                $result[] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$input = [
    [
        'drive'       => ['test1'],
        'wheel_drive' => ['2WD', '4WD']
    ],
    [
        0 => [
            'drive'       => ['test21', 'test31'],
            'wheel_drive' => ['2WD', '4WD']
        ],
        1 => [
            'drive'       => ['test32'],
            'wheel_drive' => ['4WD']
        ]
    ],
    [
        'drive'       => ['test4'],
        'wheel_drive' => ['2WD', '4WD']
    ]
];

print_r(array_flatten($input));
```